# mindate and maxdate not working in datepicker (inline method)

Tags: javascript, php, datepicker

I have worked in normal datepicker but i am new to inline datepicker, i have tried to set mindate as current date and maxdate as 1 month from today.

```
<div id="calendar" class="calendar" style="background:#e6e6e6;"></div>
    <p style="text-align:center; padding:10px 10px; background:#cc0000;">
        <input style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size:18px;" type="button" value="Book Now" onclick="checkClicked();">
    </p>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#calendar').datepicker({
            minDate: new Date(),
            maxDate: '+2m'
        });
    });
    function checkClicked() 
    {       
        var data_inicial_type = $("#calendar").datepicker('getDate');
        if( data_inicial_type === null ) 
        {
            alert("Please Select Date");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
        var data_inicial = data_inicial_type.getFullYear() + '-' + (data_inicial_type.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + data_inicial_type.getDate();
        window.location = "slot_registration.php?dateok="+data_inicial;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please help me in telling that is am taking selected date in correct way or any possible easy way is there?? because i am getting date as 28-6-2018

[image]

Comment: Which datepicker are you using ?

Comment: @VigneshRaja i have mentioned the screenshot above.. please see..

Comment: Sorry with screenshot.. we cant find which one u r using ... jquery datepicker or bootstrap datepicker

Comment: class="datepicker datepicker-inline" @VigneshRaja

Comment: Multiple datepicker can have the same class... can you please give the script that you load before u initialise it ?